# Eloquent manytomany polymorphic nested query withCount

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have the following manytomany polymorphic relationship

**Asset**

```php
public function countries()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Country', 'locationable');
}
```

**Country**

```php
public function assets()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Asset', 'locationable');
}
```

Also Category has manytomany with Assets

```php
public function assets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Asset', 'category_asset');
    }
```

I need to query a category and eager load assets that have country assigned.

Here is my eloquent query

```php
$category = Category::with(['children.assets' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('countries', function($q) {
                $q->where('code', '=', 'FR');
            });
        }])
            ->where('id', 1)
            ->first();
```

This seems to work, but then when I use the Category model with $this->assets It loads all of them, even if only one is returned in the query.

I am using API resources like so

```php
AssetResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('assets'))
```

Where can I put a condition to only use assets that passed the condition where('code', '=', 'FR')

Comment: Please add the `children` relationship. Where exactly are you using `$this->assets`?

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, I should have been making the check on the children categories like this:

```
Category::with(
                ['children' => function ($query) {
                $query->with(['children.assets' => function ($q) {
                    $q->country('GB');
                }]);
            }])
                ->where('id', 1)
                ->first();
```

Category has children categories

```
public function children()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'parent_category_child_category', 'parent_category_id', 'child_category_id');
    }
```